# use data-target and data-toggle on asp:buttonfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i am creating a web app in which i want to open a modal on button click, the button is inside grid

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="Expense" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  CommandName="Select"  />
```

this is my button in which i want to open the bootstrap modal but when i debug my program i am getting the following error

> > Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField'
>   does not have a public property named 'data-toggle'.

```
    Line 259:                 SortExpression="status" />
Line 260:             <asp:BoundField DataField="clash" HeaderText="clash" SortExpression="clash" Visible="false" />
Line 261:             <asp:ButtonField Text="Expense" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  CommandName="Select"  />   
Line 262:             <asp:ButtonField Text="Expense Details"   CommandName="Details"   />  
Line 263:         </Columns>
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a similar thing a while back but instead of using the data-toggle functionality I called the scripts from the code-behind using the following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ModalView", "<script>$('#ViewEnqDetail').modal('show');</script>", false);
```

Before the above line you can populate any controls on your modal with data that you would like to show.